# You have updates available on another account

Tags: photos.app, mac-appstore, imovie, garageband

I received this Mac as a gift. Everything worked fine, now in the App Store the default applications GarageBand, iMovie and iPhoto refuse to update, since it asks for the Apple ID of the previous owner.

So this is not like a bug other people perceive, who ever had only one AppleID its really changed ownership. When we did that, I also created a Account for me with Admin escalation, and deleted the account of the previous owner to safe any personal data.

So now how can I update these default apps that came bundled with the device? Can I deinstall'em and reinstall with my AppleID?

Its not like I want any Apps that the previous owner bought (all deinstalled and installed my ones), only those that are tied to the device.

Comment: Just for the archives:  This message can ALSO be shown if you have a program originally installed from outside the App Store which now has updates from the App Store.  You must remove the old installation and install from the App Store for this to go away - I had to with XCode.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I first got my Mac.  The first thing you want to try is going to the "Purchased" tab in the App Store and seeing if it gives you the option to "accept" the iLife apps at the top of that page.  If not, then you should contact the App Store support team using this website: http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/contact/ .  They will most likely email you back asking for your serial number to confirm that you are eligible for the apps.  For me, they validated my serial, verified that I was eligible for the apps, and issued me redemption codes for all of the iLife apps.  After that, no problems.  **If they issue you codes, make sure you uninstall the three iLife apps through Launchpad before using the codes and redownloading them.**

Answer (score 0):

Although these apps came bundled with the Mac, they are premium applications. You can try visiting an Apple store, or speaking with Apple support, to see if you are entitled to the applications complimentarily, as they did ship with your Mac. Your alternative is to delete them, and purchase iLife from the Mac App Store using your Apple ID.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to delete them either, since they belong to the Mac. At least the remove button is not there, where it is for every other app installed via the Apple store...

Comment: I would recommend backing them up (e.g. copying them from the Applications folder to a USB drive), and then deleting them from the Applications folder.